# Azure AD B2C - Sample code mods for b2clogin

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Has anyone modified the [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi) project to use 
domain.b2clogin.com
rather than
https://login.microsoftonline.com

Simply updating the Web.config for ida:AadInstance does not seem to work.  When I click on SignIn/SignUp it spins out and I get a blank browser.

Comment: Can you please paste your modified settings?